# Which programming language first introduced 'Hello World'

Tags: programming-languages, history

Which programming language first introduced 'Hello World' as a first program to code for beginners?

Comment: On an related question, the first programming language that introduced **"Good bye cruel World"** was Java   ;)  (I'm kidding)

Comment: How does this question contribute anything or is use full ? and How does it shows "research efforts" when clearly answers cite wikipedia ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The history section of [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program#History) indicates it came from C.

> ...the tradition of using the phrase "Hello, world!" as a test message was influenced by an example program in the seminal book [*The C Programming Language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29). The example program from that book prints `"hello, world"` (without capital letters or exclamation mark), and was inherited from a 1974 Bell Laboratories internal memorandum by Brian Kernighan, *Programming in C: A Tutorial*...

Comment: Had a feeling it might have been C. ;)

Comment: +1 for Wikipedia's content, but i always believe "Hello World" was author's (Programming authors) stuff rather than any language's specific.

Comment: :P same article says "Hello World" was first used in B in 1972 rather than C 1974.

Comment: What did beginners use before Hello World came about?  In BASIC I remember the classic Print "hi" Goto 10.  Can't remember what I first programmed in COBOL back in 1991.  I think there wasn't any standard 1st program.

Comment: @Ranger: Eh, my goal was to print the article as a good resource. I didn't scour the article. Also note that B and C are just different versions of the same language so it makes sense that it was actually used first in B but wasn't published as a sample until the documentation on C was produced.

Comment: B and C aren't different versions of the same language; C was a new language based on B.

Comment: It originated in Kernighan's B tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

The convention was introduced for the general public in K&R - [Kernigan and Richie: The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29) - which is the canonical introduction to C.  That book became the canonical because it was succinct reflecting in its thinness.

The updated version covering ANSI C is worth reading simply for their approach to writing documentation.